# Erro $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated

Tags: php

Após fazer o upgrade do PHP para a versão 5.6 comecei a receber a seguinte mensagem:

> **Deprecated**:  Automatically populating *$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA* is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in **Unknown** on line **0**

Existe alguma alternativa para o uso do `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` está em desuso a partir da versão 5.6 *texto grifado*, o que causa o *warning*, como descrito na documentação:

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Esta mensagem especifica `Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` ocorre quando o `php.ini` esta configurado para gerar automaticamente a variável `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` através da *flag* `always_populate_raw_post_data`.

O `always_populate_raw_post_data` por padrão é On em versões mais antigas do PHP, mas no PHP7 ele não existe mais, portanto o problema não irá ocorrer, se o seu PHP for uma versão mais antiga, então basta configurar o php.ini assim:

```
always_populate_raw_post_data=-1
```

Salvar e reiniciar o Apache/Ngnix/Lighttpd.

Como alternativa ao uso do `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` pode-se usar os [`wrappers`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/wrappers.php.php), no caso para pegar os dados de entrada usamos `php://input`

Um exemplo simples:

```
<?php
$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Se os dados forem muito grandes (extensos) você pode fazer um "loop" para a leitura, exemplo de como gravar os dados em um arquivo:

```
<?php
$fileHandle  = fopen('arquivo.txt', 'wb');
$inputHandle = fopen('php://input', 'rb');

if ($fileHandle && $inputHandle) {
    while(FALSE === feof($inputHandle)) {
        $data = fgets($inputHandle, 256);
        fwrite($fileHandle, $data);
    }

    fclose($fileHandle);
    fclose($inputHandle);
}
```

Note que você pode desligar os *warnings* e ainda usar `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, mas a partir do PHP7 ele não funciona mais, como dito anteriormente, então prefira desde já usar os *wrappers* para manter a compatibilidade.