# Como criar thumbnails de imagens de uma imagem existente dentro da pasta?

Tags: php, imagem, funções, processamento-de-imagens, thumbnail

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou aprendendo a programar, inclusive aprendendo ***MUITO*** com a ajuda de vocês que me ensinam praticamente tudo sobre `functions` e o meu problema agora é o seguinte: preciso criar `thumbnails` de diversos `width` e `height` para atender a cada área do site que tem formatos de imagem diferentes conforme a página visualizada.

Como desenvolver uma `function com PHP` que entra na pasta de ***imagens*** e faz cópias destas ***imagens*** nos tamanhos desejados tipo `620x400`, `310x200`, `155x100`?

Comment: Sua pergunta está na fila de análise de fechamento e já tem dois votos para fechar como ampla demais. Entretanto, vejo que você já é um usuário experiente por aqui e a sua pergunta me parece bem escrita, objetiva e bem especificada. Então, acho que quem votou para fechar esta pergunta deveria explicar o motivo, pois não consigo ver nada de errado com ela. Desta forma estou votando em "Deixar aberta".

Comment: também marquei para fechar como ampla demais pois há muitas variantes. Na verdade é fácil de responder e a questão não é nem tanto pelo tamanho da resposta, mas pelas diversas variantes. Exemplo, como organizar as imagens? Já pensou nisso? Evitar colisão de nomes, evitar muitos arquivos numa única pasta, etc.. E quanto precisar remover uma imagem específica ou um grupo de imagens? Se a estrutura não for boa, terá uma grande dificuldade em resolver outros problemas que vão surgindo. Por isso considero amplo demais. Procure perguntar uma parte por vez e vc mesmo junta as peças.

Comment: @DanielOmine ele só pergunta como criar, não podes ampliar a pergunta tu mesmo se o AP só quer saber um pormenor, era amplo de mais se ele perguntasse "Como posso criar, remover, pesquisar thumbs em PHP" por exemplo.

Comment: Discordo, Jorbe B. Pois insisto que uma resposta adequada seria ampla demais. Ele mesmo diz num trecho `"preciso criar thumbnails de diversos width e height"`. Imagine ele criando isso sem planejar a estrutura. E isso é o erro que todo iniciante comete. Seria simples se ele perguntasse somente `"quero redimensionar uma imagem"`. Aí sim, nesse caso ele se vira com a estrutura. Mas, não foi só isso que ele descreveu. EStá bem claro que pretende aplicar isso em várias imagens. E como eu mesmo comentei. A resposta não ficaria extensa, mas sim, complexa, com muitas variantes.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro tenha em mente que a manipulação de imagens usando o PHP (ou qualquer outra plataforma/linguagem) geralmente consome bastante memória dependendo da imagem, podendo eventualmente até causar um erro semelhante a este:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 13056 bytes) in thumbnail.php on line 36

Isto é praticamente quase impossível de resolver, você pode até amenizar usando setando no `php.ini` o `memory_limit`, mas isto não é a solução (na minha opinião), pois ainda sim isto afeta o servidor, ainda mais no seu caso que provavelmente serão várias imagens ao mesmo tempo.

Você pode sim tentar usar um script como este (renomeie o arquivo para resize.php):

```
<?php
function imageResize($path, $new_width, $new_height, $outputFolder)
{
    $mime = detectMimeType($path);

    switch ($mime) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
        break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $resource = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        break;
        case 'image/png':
            $resource = imagecreatefromgif($path);
        break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    $filename = preg_replace('#\.[a-z]+$#i', '', basename($path));

    $width  = imagesx($resource);
    $height = imagesy($resource);

    if ($new_width >= $width && $new_height >= $height) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($width > $height) {
        $percentage = $width / $new_width;
    } else {
        $percentage = $height / $new_height;
    }

    $new_width  = round($width  * $percentage);
    $new_height = round($height * $percentage);

    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    imagecopyresampled($newImage, $resource, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    $resource = NULL;

    $filename .= '[' . $new_width . 'x' . $new_height . ']';

    switch ($mime) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            imagejpeg($newImage, $outputFolder . '/' . $filename . '.jpg', 100);
        break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($newImage, $outputFolder . '/' . $filename . '.gif');
        break;
        default:
            imagepng($newImage, $outputFolder . '/' . $filename . '.png');
    }

    $newImage = NULL;
}

function detectMimeType($file)
{
    $mime = '';
    if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mime  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
        $mime = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mime;
}
```

O uso ficaria algo como:

```
<?php
include 'resize.php';

$pastaDestino = 'redimensionadas/';
$arquivos = 'originais/';

//Pega todas imagens
$lista = glob($arquivos . '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($lista as $file) {
     //Se o arquivo se chamar foto.jpg gera um arquivo com o nome "foto[155x100].jpg"
     imageResize($file, 155, 100, $pastaDestino);

     //Gera um arquivo com o nome "foto[310x200].jpg"
     imageResize($file, 310, 200, $pastaDestino);

     //Gera um arquivo com o nome "foto[620x400].jpg"
     imageResize($file, 620, 400, $pastaDestino);
}
```

No entanto como eu disse isto pode gerar um alto consumo de memória o que pode afetar um pouco o servidor (se o script for usado muitas vezes) e dependendo do tamanho da imagem pode ocorrer o erro já citado *Allowed memory size*.

O que recomendo é tentar usar Javascript no front-end e upload usando ajax, veja um exemplo aqui funcional em outra resposta minha:

- [Uso de memória imagens PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63018/3635)

A única diferença é que ao invés de usar `<input type=file>` você deverá fazer assim:

```
<?php
$arquivos = 'originais/';

//Pega todas imagens
$lista = glob($arquivos . '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE);
?>

<script>
<?php foreach ($lista as $file): ?>
<?php
    $filename = preg_replace('#\.[a-z]+$#i', '', basename($path));
?>
    var pathfile = "<?php echo $file; ?>";
    var filename = "<?php echo $filename; ?>";

    //155x100
    compressImage(pathfile, 155, 100, "jpeg", function(resource) {
        uploadAjax(resource, filename . '[155x100].jpg', function(response) {
            if (response === "OK") {
                alert("sucesso");
            } else {
                alert("Ajax: " + response);
            }
        }, function(errStatus) {
            alert("erro: " + errStatus);
        });
    });

    //310x200
    compressImage(pathfile, 310, 200, "jpeg", function(resource) {
        uploadAjax(resource, filename . '[310x200].jpg', function(response) {
            if (response === "OK") {
                alert("sucesso");
            } else {
                alert("Ajax: " + response);
            }
        }, function(errStatus) {
            alert("erro: " + errStatus);
        });
    });

    //620x400
    compressImage(pathfile, 620, 400, "jpeg", function(resource) {
        uploadAjax(resource, filename . '[620x400].jpg', function(response) {
            if (response === "OK") {
                alert("sucesso");
            } else {
                alert("Ajax: " + response);
            }
        }, function(errStatus) {
            alert("erro: " + errStatus);
        });
    });

<?php endforeach; ?>
</script>
```

> Note que o pathfile ou $file no caso, devem conter um caminho acessível publicamente (via http).

No arquivo *upload.php* (da outra pergunta) troque:

```
define('PASTA_UPLOAD', '/home/user/projeto/data');
```

Pelo caminho desejado aonde ficarão salva as imagens.