# Diminuir o tamanho de um arquivo(imagem) no PHP

Tags: php

Possuo uma página que faz upload de imagens. Porém existe um tamanho máximo, um número de KB máximos que ao ser ultrapassado não deixam terminar o upload. Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de diminuir o tamanho das imagens(Em KB) ao serem escolhidas.
Quando a imagem for selecionada, antes de transferir o arquivo para a pasta do meu servidor, gostaria que fosse reduzido o tamanho da imagem, pois ao exceder certo tamanho de KBytes, o upload não é finalizado.
 Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Eu acredito que esta resposta que fiz deve resolver o seu problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63018/3635

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível manipular a imagem que está no lado cliente, dentro do contexto da pergunta.

## Plugin

Uma opção seria instalar algum plugin no browser do cliente e então por meio desse plugin seria executado um software de edição de imagem previamente instalado no cliente. Isso é uma opção que pode ser viável para um públcio alvo pequeno e restrito. Para um ambiente público é inviável. Para ambos os casos, o custo é alto pois precisa desenvolver um plugin ou talvez consiga encontrar uma solução paga.

## Software no cliente

Numa segunda opção instalar um software no cliente somente para fazer o upload das imagens. E nesse software faria a comunicação com algum editor de imagens ou dentro do proprio software possuir tal recurso. Assim com a primeira opção, pode ser dsenvolvido do zero ou comprar soluções prontas.

## Processo manual

Outra opção é o usuário usar um software editor de imagens para tornar a imagem dentro do padrão exigido. Ou seja, um processo manual.
Esse é o mais usado por ser simples e sem custos adicionais.

Comment: Entendi.. Você poderia me enviar algum exemplo dessa primeira opção que você citou? Seria de grande ajuda. Obrigado.

Comment: No google, pesquise por "plugin image editor client side" e termos semelhantes a isso.

Answer (score 0):

**É possivel sim manipular a imagem no lado cliente** e reduzi-la antes de enviar para o servidor, você usar JavaScript com [`File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) + [`Canvas API` (HTML5)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) e [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (o Ajax é opicional, você pode salvar os dados da imagem gerada em um `<input>` ou `<textarea>` oculto também), como descrevi nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63018/3635

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function compressImage(file, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT, format, response) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    var reader = new FileReader();    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        img.src = e.target.result;

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var width  = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        if (width > height) {
            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                width = MAX_WIDTH;
            }
        } else if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
        }

        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

        response(
            canvas.toDataURL("image/" + format).replace(/^data[:]image\/(.*);base64,/, "")
        );
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function uploadAjax(data, fileName, success, error)
{
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    oReq.open("POST", "upload.php?filename=" + fileName, true);
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
            if (oReq.status === 200) {
                success(oReq.responseText);
            } else {
                error(oReq.status);
            }
        }
    };
    oReq.send(data);
}

function enviar() {
    var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('input').files;

    //Gerar imagem com tamanho normal
    compressImage(filesToUpload[0], 800, 600, "jpeg", function(resource) {
        uploadAjax(resource, filesToUpload[0].name, function(response) {
            if (response === "OK") {
                alert("sucesso");
            } else {
                alert("Ajax: " + response);
            }
        }, function(errStatus) {
            alert("erro: " + errStatus);
        });
    });

    //Gerar imagem com thumb
    compressImage(filesToUpload[0], 150, 150, "jpeg", function(resource) {
        uploadAjax(resource, filesToUpload[0].name.replace(/\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/, "_thumb.$1"), function(response) {
            if (response === "OK") {
                alert("sucesso");
            } else {
                alert("Ajax: " + response);
            }
        }, function(errStatus) {
            alert("erro: " + errStatus);
        });
    });
}
</script>

<p>
    <input type="file" value="" id="input">
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="send">
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('send').onclick = enviar;
</script>
```

O PHP deve ser algo como (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50982/3635):

```
<?php
define('PASTA_UPLOAD', '/home/user/projeto/data');

if (isset($_GET['filename']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $cl = (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];

    $tmpFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '~upload-');

    $file = fopen($tmpFile, 'w');
    $fh   = fopen('php://input', 'r');
    if ($file && $fh) {
        $data = '';
        while (FALSE === feof($fh)) {
            $data .= fgets($fh, 256);
        }
        fwrite($file, base64_decode($data));
    }

    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
    }

    if ($fh) {
        fclose($fh);
    }

    echo 'OK';
    copy($tmpFile, PASTA_UPLOAD . '/' . $_GET['filename']);
} else {
    echo 'Requisição inválida';
}
```